# distribution of 101 coins to three friends

Tags: permutations

In how many ways we can distribute 101 coins to three friends such that sum of the coins of two friends is more than or equal to the number of coins of third friend.
my views:should I distribute 50 and then 51 ,52 coins  ....is there any elegant way please guide

Comment: Do you mean the sum of any two friends is more than the third or specific friends: $friend_1$ and $friend_2$ together are more than or equal to $friend_3$?

Comment: This has something to do with the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)...

Comment: Additional query - can a friend receive zero coins or only strictly positive amounts?

Comment: Ian, no. Because if so, then one of the other friends have more coins than the other. Adding zero and the smallee of the two numbers is less than the greater number, which contradicts what we want to count.

Comment: @Asemismaiel I was hoping for an comment addressing both queries. If its any two friends then $\{0,50,51\}$ does get counted (if zero is allowed) as $0+51>50$.

Comment: @IanMiller no is not correct because $ 0 + 50 < 51 $

Comment: @Anonymous Hence why I asked if it is 'any two friend' or 'specific friends'. If he just wants any two friends to have more than the third person it is different than if he wants friends A and B to have more than friend C which is different again to all combinations of 'any two friends' more than the other.

Comment: @IanMiller I believe since the problem doesn't mention any labels for friends the "third" or "ordered" friend is arbitrary.

Comment: This is http://oeis.org/A069981, where it says $a(n)=(n+8)(n-2)/8$ for $n$ even and $(n^2-1)/8$ for $n$ odd.  Plugging in $n=101$ gives $a(n)=1275$

Answer (score 3):

$$
x+y+z=101
$$
$$
x+y \geq z \quad x+z \geq y \quad y+z \geq x
$$
$$
x+y= 101-z \geq z \rightarrow z\leq 50
$$
$$
x+z= 101-y \geq y \rightarrow y\leq 50
$$
$$
y+z= 101-x \geq x \rightarrow x\leq 50
$$

$$
x = 50 - u \quad y = 50 - v \quad z = 50 - w
$$
$$
(50 - u) + (50 - v) + (50 - w) = 101
$$
$$
u + v + w = 49 \Rightarrow 0 \leq u + v = 49 - w \leq 49
$$
$$
u+v = i : \{0\leq i \leq 49\}
$$

$$
u+v = i \rightarrow (u = 0, v = i) \dots (u=i, v=0) \Rightarrow i+1 \mbox{ways}
$$

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{49}i+1 = 1275
$$

Comment: http://ideone.com/R5rQzu shows the result algoirthmically

Comment: There you go! :D

Comment: little bit my views since u+v+w=49 so number of non negative solutions are C(51,2)

Comment: @mun yes my friend that is correct, but If I did that I would have to explain why C(n,2). Also you can consider upvoting if you liked the answer and mark it as accepted answer :)